# Slideshow wallpaper using files in hidden folder

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, wallpaper, live-wallpaper, sony-xperia-p

I've got some nice photos in one folder and their specially cropped versions in another hidden folder (the name starts with a dot).

How can I use the cropped photos from the hidden folder for a wallpaper slideshow? No matter what app I try to use, it doesn't allow me to use the hidden photos. I don't want to make them visible; I don't want duplicated photos in my gallery app.

Is there any way / app that would allow me to use the hidden photos for a wallpaper slideshow without having to make them visible in my gallery app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android treats filenames that start with a dot as hidden. So, there's no way for any app to show them. However, you can still see them on a file explorer that can see hidden files (may need root access).

Comment: So there is no way to do what I wanted to do?

Comment: @burtek Most likely, no. I think it's only natural for apps to respect the hidden property.